# Navigation buttons on a carousel

Tags: html

I have put a carousel in my web page with two buttons for left and right but I'm struggling to work out why the buttons aren't spinning the carousel around.

Here is my code:

```
<!--Carousel Start-->
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h3>Featured advertisements</h3></div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-md-12">
<div class="homeCarousel" id="featuredCarousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">
<div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e477e4/fff&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#featuredCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#featuredCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing the carousel class on the #featuredCarousel. Also if you want the sliding effect, you need to add slide class as well.

```
<!--Carousel Start-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h3>Featured advertisements</h3></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="homeCarousel carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="featuredCarousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e477e4/fff&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#featuredCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#featuredCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/z7rqe1qg/

Check bootstrap documentation for more settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
<div class="homeCarousel" id="featuredCarousel">
```

it should read as follows

```
<div class="homeCarousel carousel slide" id="featuredCarousel" data-ride="carousel">
```

presuming that you are using the standard carousel from bootstrap